# iterating the loop

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is my original plunker demo http://plnkr.co/edit/9UBZ9E4uxAo1TXXghm1T?p=preview .

For div 4(ng-if="show==4") When the list is empty i want to hide the particular div, currently each div is shown for a interval of 5 seconds, any inputs?As we are showing each div based on $interval, need to modify the js code to hide the div if the `detailsList==0`.

JS code:

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $rootScope, $interval) {
  $scope.show = 1;
  $rootScope.detailsList = 0;

  $interval(function() {

    if ($scope.show === 4) {
      if ($rootScope.detailsList < 2) {
        ++$rootScope.detailsList;
      } else {
        $rootScope.detailsList = 0;
        $scope.show = 1;
      }
    } else if ($scope.show < 4) {
      ++$scope.show;
    } else {
      $scope.show = 1;
    }
  }, 5000, 0);

});
```

Comment: Can you provide what is the expected result , you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @divyareddy - Please find the demo http://plnkr.co/edit/9UBZ9E4uxAo1TXXghm1T?p=preview
In the above plnkr demo, $scope.details length is zero, i dont want to load div4 when $scope.details length is zero. Even when ng-hide is used, the div is loaded as we are using $interval to load each div.

Comment: you want to hide the div .. when your details length is zero or detailsList ==0 ?

Comment: I want to hide the div when details length is zero..@vertika

Answer (score 0):

Use one start variable to control the $interval for example as mentioned below

```
$scope.start = 1 ; // 1 to start and 0 to stop
```

Updated controller login with above mentioned start variable

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope,$rootScope, $interval) {
    $scope.show = 1;
    $rootScope.detailsList = 0;
    $scope.start = 1;

    var intervalPromise = $interval(function() {

        if($scope.start ==1){
        if ($scope.show === 4) {
          if ($rootScope.detailsList < 2) {
            ++$rootScope.detailsList;
          } else {
            $rootScope.detailsList = 0;
            $scope.show = 1;
            $scope.start =0;
          }
        }
        else if ($scope.show < 4) {
            ++$scope.show; 
        } else {
            $scope.show = 1;

                }

}
        }, 1000, 0);




});
```

Comment: The suggested code doesn't seem to work, pls find updated plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/mZRvsFNJY3DRcUhRQrA8?p=preview.
It is loading the empty div for 1st interval(blank page can be seen for 5seconds after 3333333 is shown when  $scope.detailsList1 length is zero.@divya reddy

Comment: @user8727958, you said that you want to hide the div when details length is zero right, please find the codepen for reference- https://codepen.io/divyar34/pen/WXRNeV

Answer (score 0):

Well ! you dont show your div with `show==4` condition.
Instead take another variable to show div tag :

I have changed your controller by adding a new variable `showDivFour` :

Coontroller :

```
 app.controller('MainController', function($scope,$rootScope, $interval) {
$scope.show = 1;
$rootScope.detailsList = 0;
$scope.showDivfour = false;

$interval(function() {
   if ($scope.show === 4) {

      if ($rootScope.detailsList < 2) {
        ++$rootScope.detailsList;
      } else {
        $rootScope.detailsList = 0;
        $scope.show = 1;
      }
      if($rootScope.detailsList!=0){
        $scope.showDivenfour = true;
      }else{
        $scope.showDivenfour = false;
      }
    }
    else if ($scope.show < 4) {
        ++$scope.show; 
    } else {
        $scope.show = 1;
    }

    }, 5000, 0);



});
```

Your html :

change :

```
<div ng-if="showDivfour" ng-controller="detailsController" >

     <div >
       <h1>  {{details[detailsList].name}}   </h1>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please find the updated code http://plnkr.co/edit/qDcJ51CunMkWLZj5en9c?p=preview . It is loading the div first and then checking the condition as we have given if($scope.show < 4){  ++$scope.show; }.